# How can I submit selected values using Ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a onlineshop asp.net mvc application.

My database contains 2 table: Categories and Products

**Categories Table:**

.CategoriesID

.CategoriesName

**Products Table:**

.Product ID

.ProducName

.ProductPrice

.ProductPicture

.Category_ID

.CategoryNname

MyViewModel Class Contains the lists of the 2 tables and a variable.

```
  public class MyViewModel
    {
      public List<Category> CategoriesV { get; set; }
      public List<Product> ProductsV { get; set; }
      public int SumVM { get; set; }

    }
 }
```

My index View has the Partial View of all the categories, and the product of each categories.

_Categories Partial View

```
@model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetCatItems", "Home", new AjaxOptions()))
{
    foreach (Category item in Model.CategoriesV)
    {
        <div id="CategoryId">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" 
        value="@item.CategoriesName" name="CategName"  />
        </div>
      }
    }
```

_Categories Controller

```
  public ActionResult _Categories()
     {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            ProductsV = DB.Products.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The GetCatItems fetch the products of each category.

_GetCatItems PartialView

```
  @model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel 
   @foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsV)
    {

        if (item.Category_Name ==Session["id"].ToString())
        {
            <tr>
                <td scope="row"><img src="@Url.Content(@item.ProductImage)" width="150" height="200" /></td>
                <td>
                    @item.ProductName
                    <br />Price : @item.ProductPrice $<br /> @item.ProductDetails
                </td>

                <input  type="submit" value="@item.ProductPrice"  name="ProductPrice" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddtoCart", 
   "Home")'">Add to cart </input>

            </tr>
    }}
```

_GetCatItems Controller

```
     public ActionResult GetCatItems(string CategName)
     {

        Session["id"] = CategName;
        var viewM = new MyViewModel()
        {
            ProductsV = DB.Products.ToList()
        };           
        return View(viewM);
     }
```

Finally I have a DIV that I want to add selected items total price in it

```
<div id="element"
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
Added to Cart<br />
Total : @Model.SumVM.ToString()  <text>$</text>
</div>
 </div>
```

AddtoCart Controller take the value from the input tag in GetCatItems

AddtoCart Controller

```
   public ActionResult AddtoCart(int ProductPrice)

        {

            var viewModel = new MyViewModel
            {
                SumVM = ProductName 
            };

            return View(viewModel);
         }
```

What I tried to is wrap the input element inside an AjaxBegin Form Like this

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddtoCart", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "element", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
  {

  <input  type="submit" value="100" class="btn-outline- 
 primary" name="Value" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddtoCart", 
   "Home")'">Add to cart </input>
  }
```

but it didn't work but when tried to do is to change AjaxBegin Form with

```
  Html.beginform("AddtoCart", "Home",FormMethod.Post)
```

it worked but its shows the add to cart div in a new page(I want it in the same page).

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you can use jquery to do call controller and return json from backend, when success callback returns you just update div that holds your Total

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ActionResult AddtoCart(int Value)

    {

        Session["items"]= Convert.ToInt32(Session["items"]) + 1;
        Session["sum"] = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sum"]) + Value;

        var viewModel = new MyViewModel
        {
            itemsNumbers= Convert.ToInt32(Session["items"]),
            SumVM = Convert.ToInt32(Session["sum"])
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

GetCatItems Partial View:

```
  @model OnlineShopping.MyViewModel

      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddtoCart", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId 
     = "element", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
     {
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Image</th>
            <th>Products Details</th>
            <th>Add To Cart</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach (Product item in Model.ProductsV)
        {

            if (item.Category_Name == Session["id"].ToString())
            {
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row"><img src="@Url.Content(@item.ProductImage)" 
       width="150" height="200" /></td>
                    <td>
                        @item.ProductName
                        <br />Price : @item.ProductPrice $<br /> @item.ProductDetails
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="@item.ProductPrice" name="Value" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
 }
```